# Select MAX( valuename ) from table sqlite javasctipt plugin is unaccesible

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

If i query

```
 tx.executeSql(' SELECT MAX(valuename) as "value"  FROM table ;', [], function(tx, result)
```

or

```
 tx.executeSql(' SELECT MAX(valuename) as value  FROM table ;', [], function(tx, result)
```

or

```
 tx.executeSql(' SELECT MAX(valuename) FROM table ;', [], function(tx, result)
```

The value is not reachable via

```
alert("ans:"+result.rows.item(0).valuename);
```

nor via

```
alert("ans:"+result.rows.item(0).value);
```

in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Access the attribute with brackets:

```
result.rows.item(0)["MAX(valuename)"]
```